# How to revert Android Studio toolbar to be shown in the bottom (like previous version)?

Tags: android-studio

The "run", "terminal" and other menus is shown on the bottom left side in the new Android Studio as in the image:

[image]

I want to revert it so it is shown in the bottom (like the old design)

[image]

How can I do this ?

I find the older design better and more accessible. I want the "terminal" "git" "todo" "problems" in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself

Go to settings -> apparence -> new ui -> disable it!

[image]